# Apply same configurations to different tasks

Tags: groovy, gradle

For example I've got two closures in `subprojects` configuration (for example `task1` - `task2`)

```
subprojects { 
    task1 {
        config 1
        config 2
    }
    task2 {
        config 1
        config 2
    }
}
```

How to apply same configuration for both tasks at once?

I was trying to do something like:

```
task1, task2 { 
    config 1
    config 2
}
```

or:

```
task2 {
    task1
}
```

However it does not work. How to do it correct if it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
[task1, task2].each { t ->
   configure(t) {
      config1
      config2
   }
}
```

Comment: @Opal , how can I add this code ? ---for idea and eclipse>>>>>> 
idea, eclipse {
    module {
        excludeDirs -= file("$buildDir/")
        sourceDirs += file(generatedSrcDir)
    }

}

Comment: @smilyface, sorry don't understand. Maybe just add a new question?

Comment: @Opal , Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031863/gradle-how-to-combine-same-code-of-different-tasks