# How to combine same code of different tasks

Tags: gradle, task, build.gradle

This question is related to [Apply same configurations to different tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881025/apply-same-configurations-to-different-tasks/32881292?noredirect=1#comment53885257_32881292)

In gradle, I have this piece of configuration:

```
idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs -= file("$buildDir/")
        sourceDirs += file(generatedSrcDir)
    } 
}
```

I have another one for eclipse with same code.

Question:

```
idea, eclipse {
    module {
        excludeDirs -= file("$buildDir/")
        sourceDirs += file(generatedSrcDir)
    }
}
```

is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do would be written as the following:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

ext.generatedSrcDir = project.file('.')

[idea, eclipse].each {
    configure(it) {
        module {
            excludeDirs -= file("$buildDir/")
            sourceDirs += file(generatedSrcDir)
        }
    }
}
```

but since `eclipse` extension does not expose `module` method/field it will not work. Unfortunately you need to configure both `idea` and `eclipse` separately. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750869/how-to-add-gradle-generated-source-folder-to-eclipse-project) is a question on configuring additional source folder for eclipse.

Comment: yea.. you are right. It is not working for eclipse as it does not have module. Thank you for the new link. That was a new learning.

Comment: @smilyface, if you found my answer helpful, please accept it :)